# Using RichText in a map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prismic.io

Thank you so, so much for your time looking at this

I'm using React and Prismic
I'm trying to apply RichText (https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/rendering-the-rich-text-and-title-field-reactjs) to render the text but do not work on map.

My guess is that I'm loosing some logic here but I can't understand what is
This show the content without rendering:

```
{prismicDoc?.data?.contenido?.map(x => x?.text || null)}
```

This show me an error:

```
{RichText.render(prismicDoc?.data?.contenido?.map(x => x?.text || null))}
```

The error is
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Laura

Comment: where is prismicDoc being defined?

Comment: At the begging of the class:
const SinglePage = ({ match }) => {
    const [prismicDoc, setPrismicDoc] = useState(null);
    const [notFound, toggleNotFound] = useState(false);
    const uid = match.params.uid;
    // Get the blog post document from Prismic
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPrismicData = async () => {
            try {
                const doc = await client.getByUID('paginas', uid);

                if (doc) {
                    setPrismicDoc(doc);